# Batch Entry 0 insert into PGSQL-Call getNextException to see the cause

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, exception, batch-processing

I am trying to find regular expression and if there are some duplicates, keep the unique ones and put the rest in a trash table. 
but I get this Erro which I do not know what it is!
Here is my code:

```
public class RegexRemoverMain {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    //Connection Parameters and Connect to Postgres Database
    String data = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres";
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    Connection conn = null;
    //Connect to DB
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            data, "username", "password");
    //statements to get distinct owners
    Statement ownerSt = conn.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    //statement to get Image Ids of a user
    Statement ownersImagesIdsSt = conn.createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
            ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    String insertSQL;
    //an arraylist to store unique titles+tags reported by user
    ArrayList<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    //list for storing those Ids of a users which are filtered
    List<String> filteredIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    //list for storing those Ids of a users which are kept
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

    //get the list of all the users
    ResultSet distinctOwner = ownerSt.executeQuery("select distinct owner from \"flickrData_bulkUploadedFree\"");
    distinctOwner.last();
    distinctOwner.beforeFirst();
    int count=0;
    //RegularExpression Pattern
    String theRegex= "((DSC)?(dsc)?(img)?(IMG)?(\\s?)(\\_?)((\\-?))[0-9]{1,9})";
    Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);
    //loop is going through all user's Images and check whether their the titles is one of the patterns if yes, check their title+description which are unique or not
    //if yes, we keep them; if not; we throw them away or store in another place
    while(distinctOwner.next()){
        count =  count++;
        Statement insertSt = conn.createStatement(
                ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        //store filtered images
        String insertString = "INSERT INTO regexIamges"
                + "( id , owner, descriptio, title, tags) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(insertString);
        //for each user exist in "flickrData_bulkUploadedFree"
        String owner = distinctOwner.getString("owner");
        ResultSet ownersImages;
        ownersImages = ownersImagesIdsSt.executeQuery("select id, title, tags, descriptio from \"flickrData_bulkUploadedFree\" where owner = '" + owner +"';");
        ownersImages.last();
        ownersImages.beforeFirst();
        //an list of images of a user's with the information about id, title, tags and descriptions in order to find unique Images
        ArrayList<List<String>> bulkUploadList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        while(ownersImages.next()){
            String id = ownersImages.getString("id");
            String title = ownersImages.getString("title");
            String tags = ownersImages.getString("tags");
            String description = ownersImages.getString("descriptio");
            Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(title);
            if (regexMatcher.find()){
                if(regexMatcher.group().length() != 0){
                    List<String> rowsList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    rowsList.add(id);
                    rowsList.add(title);
                    rowsList.add(tags);
                    rowsList.add(description);
                    bulkUploadList.add(rowsList);
                    bulkUploadList.add(rowsList);
                }
            }
            else{
                insertSQL = "INSERT INTO \"regBulkfreeFlickrData\" SELECT * FROM  \"flickrData_bulkUploadedFree\" where id ='"+id+"';";
                insertSt.addBatch(insertSQL);
             }
        }
        HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for(List<String> item : bulkUploadList) {
            String title, tags, id, desc, uniqueString;
            title = item.get(1);
            tags = item.get(2);
            id = item.get(0);
            desc = item.get(3);
            uniqueString = (tags + "#" + desc).trim().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(item);
            if(!hashSet.contains(uniqueString)) {
                result.add(item);
                hashSet.add(uniqueString);
                insertSQL = "INSERT INTO \"regBulkfreeFlickrData\" SELECT * FROM  \"flickrData_bulkUploadedFree\" where id ='"+id+"';";
                insertSt.addBatch(insertSQL);
            } else {
                // System.out.println("Filtered element " + uniqueString + "id " + id);
                filteredIds.add(id);
                preparedStatement.setString(1, id);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, owner);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, desc);
                preparedStatement.setString(4, title);
                preparedStatement.setString(5, tags);
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
            }
        }

        preparedStatement.executeBatch();
        preparedStatement.close();
        insertSt.executeBatch();
        insertSt.close();
    }
}
```

and the Error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO regexIamges( id , owner, descriptio, title, tags) VALUES('4292220054.0000000000000','23352125@N07','NoValue','IMG_2720','NoValue') was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2743)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1928)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:405)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2892)
at uzh.textmining.RegexRemoverMain.main(RegexRemoverMain.java:116)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

and the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "RegexImages"
(id numeric,
  owner character varying(254),
  descriptio character varying(254),
  title character varying(254),
  tags character varying(254),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Try to catch the exception and call ex.getNextException() and post the result

Comment: Actually I o not use try catch that Often, so that, I tried to use it but I got errors. I do not now where I should put it exactly

Comment: Do like this :try{
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            }catch(BatchUpdateException e){
                throw e.getNextException();
            }
            finally {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

Comment: thanks, I did it and I've got that the name of table in my code is not correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks hasnae;
I used try catch and I got that the tableName in my code does not match the table Name in database.
another problem was the name of the table: I change all the letters to lower case to solve all the errors.

Answer (score 3):

A problem that looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39227828/755804

(spoiler:
The total number of values, that is, the number of columns multiplied by the number of rows must not exceed 32767 for a single INSERT statement.
You can divide 32767 by the number of columns to get the maximal number of rows per one SQL INSERT statement.)