# UnableToExecuteStatementException: Batch entry was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause

Tags: java, sql

Using `@SqlBatch` to batch update the DB

```
@SqlBatch("<SQL Command>")
@BatchChunkSize(INSERT_BATCH_SIZE)
void insert(@BindBean Iterator<SomeObj> someObj);
```

and I'm getting this error:

> org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 ... was aborted. Call
>   getNextException to see the cause.

The problem is the exception that's being caught is a `UnableToExecuteStatementException` and not the original `BatchUpdateException`, so I am unable to call `getNextException` to see the cause. Furthermore, I can run the SQL command in the DB directly just fine.

Any idea how to get to the bottom of the cause or what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2):

I have just seen a thing like that with Hibernate and Postgres. As I understand, the problem is in the PostgreSQL driver (org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl).

What I saw was:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO myscheme.table_name (list,of,column,names,...) VALUES (9007199314139196, 'F', 27, 625, 625, 625, 625, 625, 28), (9007199314139198, 'T', 2395, 2369, 2369, 2369, 2369, 2369, 2389), ... was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

Uninformative.

I caught and printed the exception,

```
    } catch(JDBCConnectionException t) {
        System.out.println("================ {{{");
        SQLException current = t.getSQLException();
        do {
           current.printStackTrace();
        } while ((current = current.getNextException()) != null);
        System.out.println("================ }}}");
        throw t;
    }
```

and got:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Tried to send an out-of-range integer as a 2-byte value: 33300
```

Still confusing. 33300 is a very strange number. What is important is that it is a multiple of the number of columns.

The exception happens

```
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendParse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1329)
```

which is

```
pgStream.SendInteger2(params.getParameterCount()); // # of parameter types specified
```

What does that mean?

***The total number of values, that is, the number of columns multiplied by the number of rows must not exceed 32767 for a single INSERT statement.***

You can divide 32767 by the number of columns to get the maximal number of rows per one SQL INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue importing from Aurora (MySQL) to Redshift using a DataPipeline CopyActivity. 
I was able to solve it by casting the incoming data to the proper target table types in the insertQuery like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, bigint_col, timestamp_col) VALUES (?,cast(? as bigint),cast(? as timestamp))
```