# Mule DB connector copy command

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I am trying to run copy command using mule db connector. I chose Bulk Execute Operation and mentioned the copy command to read the file and load to a table. I am facing the below exception.

Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 COPY student (sname,uno )
FROM '/xx/xx/students.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2762)

Does mule support copy command?

Comment: `Call getNextException to see the cause` I guess this could help you ;) you can add an exception strategy with custom java code or somehting else that will display the cause using `getNextException()`. This answer contains a snippet of code you can re-use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39150341/unabletoexecutestatementexception-batch-entry-was-aborted-call-getnextexceptio/39227828#39227828

Answer (score 0):

Exception was because of read permissions issue on the file.